# What does "DIMM socket support" mean in a QVL (Qualified Vendors List) over RAMS for a motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, ddr3

If you look at the DDR3 1333 Qualified Vendors List (QVL) list for the Asus Z87-A motherboard:

http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1150/Z87-A/Z87-A_DRAM_QVL_0730.pdf

You can see a column called "DIMM socket support (Optional)":

[image]

1. What does this mean?
2. What does this specifically mean for a memory that only has a dot in the "2 DIMM" column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DIMM stands for [Dual In-line Memory Module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIMM) and is the RAM module(s) on a mother board.

A dot in the 2 DIMM column means the memory will work when you put in two sticks of RAM. If there are 4 slots on the motherboard, you would put it in slots and 1 and 3 (normally, consult the motherboard user guide to be sure).

A dot in the in 4 DIMM column means the memory works when using 4 sticks of RAM.

If there is no dot, as in the case of the 1 DIMM column, then it indicates that the motherboard manufacturer did not test the memory using only stick of RAM.

If you read at the bottom of the PDF you linked to, it tells you...

> • 1 DIMM: Supports one module inserted in any slot as Single-channel memory configuration
>   • 2 DIMM: Supports one pair of modules inserted into eithor the yellow slots or the dark brown slots as one pair of Dual-channel memory configuration
>   • 4 DIMM: Supports 4 modules inserted into both the yellow and dark brown slots as two pairs of Dual-channel memory configuration

Comment: So if a certain memory has a dot in the "2 DIMM" column, they have tested and verified it by actually using separate physical memory cards? That's really annoying. Planning on buying a 8GB card, but according to the QVL the motherboard only "supports" if you have 2 of them (due to a dot in the "2 DIMM" column.

Comment: Do you know what the "optional" might refer too?

Comment: `> motherboard only "supports" if you have 2 of them` - that is normally due to the fact that you need to fill all 'positions' of the databus - one module might provide e.g. 32 bits of data at a time, the MB/CPU may need 64 at a time.