# How do you read DIMM Socket Support in Memory QVL?

Tags: memory, motherboard, desktop-computer, computer-building, components

There is a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/794563/what-does-dimm-socket-support-mean-in-a-qvl-qualified-vendors-list-over-rams), but still I am not sure that DIMM Socket Support means the number of sockets NEEDED or SUPPORTED?

For example, take a look at the supported Corsair RAM for Taichi X399 mother bother
[image]
[LINK](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/X399%20Taichi/index.asp#Memory)

`XXGB` in the Corsair code is the total size of the RAM package.

1. In the first row: does `2` means 2 sockets are needed to install this package (2X16GB)? Or does it say, you cannot use another 3 packages to use all 8 available sockets (8x16GB)?
2. In the last row: DIMM Socket Support is `2`, but you need at least 4 sockets to install 64GB of 16GB size (4X16GB) (MX in the code is the number of modules).

OR in the case of Patriot RAMs
[image]

Rows 4-7 are similar packages of 2X8GB. What is the difference between `2/4/8` and `2/4` rows? Does it mean that you can use 8 sockets of the motherboard for row #5 to install 64GB and for the rest, only 4 sockets are supported to install 32GB?